# Sending Email using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the following error while trying to send an email.

```
 Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Code that sends the email

```
 Reminder.new_event(event_owner.email).deliver!
```

My Email settings are

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "google.com",
    :authentication =>"login",
    :user_name => "email address",
    :password => "password",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Could you please help me. Thanks

Comment: Is it working with any other SMTP setting? I mean to another email server? You need to localize if the problem is only connecting to gmail or to all smtp servers. Is this problem intermitten or has it never ever worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port => 587,
:domain => "google.com",
:authentication =>"plain",
:user_name => "email address",
:password => "password",
}
```

Note the:

```
:authentication =>"plain",
```

and

```
:enable_starttls_auto => true
```

is the default value, no need to specify it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I dont see any error in the log but still the mail is not getting delivered. When I tried to execute the method from the rails console, I am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your config/application.rb file :

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "google.com",
  :authentication =>"plain",
  :user_name => "email address",
  :password => "password",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

To send the email, try (note, without ! at the end)

```
Reminder.new_event(event_owner.email).deliver
```

And try sending a test email to an email address that is not the same as the sending gmail account (as gmail won't allow that through).

Answer (score 0):

I did only have success when omitting both :port and :domain, but had to set :tls to true.

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { 
    :tls => true,
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com", 
    :authentication => :plain, 
    :user_name => "full-email-address", 
    :password => "password" 
  }
```